# Broken Display Matrix Program m*n

Tags: java

I know this is an armature question, but I can't seem to find the error that occurs for the number of rows that the user inputs. When I input the number or rows, it completely ignores that command. Only the column works for both the number of rows and columns.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DisplayMatrix
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the number of columns: ");
                int m = input.nextInt();
                
                printMat(m);
        printMatrix(n);
    }

   public static void printMatrix(int n) {
        for (int rows = 0; rows < n; rows++) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print((int)(Math.random() * 2));
        }
     }  
     
   public static void printMat(int m) {
           for (int cols = 0; cols < m; cols ++) {
                System.out.print((int)(Math.random() * 2));
            }
         }
}
```

Comment: You are printing one row of n length and one row of m length. Not an actual matrix.To print a matrix answer from Gaurav is correct: you have to nest 2 for-loops one inside the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for printing matrix you can use the loop like:

```
for(int rows=0;rows<n;rows++){
for(int col=0;col<m;col++){
 System.out.print((int)(Math.random() * 2)+ " ");
}
System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: you can make function : printMatrix(int n,int m){ //code here }  then call printmatrix(n,m); in main function